# How to run a .jar file

Tags: java

I'm new to programming and I just made a project that reverses a string.
Here is the source code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class ReverseofaString
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        ReverseofaString rev=new ReverseofaString();
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a string : ");
        String  str=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Reverse of a String  is : "+rev.reverse(str));
    }
    static String reverse(String s)
    {
        String rev="";
        for(int j=s.length();j>0;--j)
        {
            rev=rev+(s.charAt(j-1));
        }
        return rev;
    }
}
```

How do I run it as a jar?

I tried
double clicking the .jar file, nothing happened
I also tried `java -jar test.jar` in cmd but it returned `Error: Unable to access jarfile test.jar`

Comment: Have you created a jar yet? Source code on its own is a `.java` file. You don't automatically get a `.jar` every time you write Java code.

Answer (score 0):

you need to build it as a JAR file first (lookup how to do this for your IDE), then when you cd the folder with the .jar file you should be able to run "java -jar test.jar"... if you want to run your program without creating a .jar, you can always just type

> javac yourFile.java

> java yourFile

in the terminal.